# Displaying Random Banner on page load

Tags: javascript

I've created some JS that will display a random page banner when a user loads the page.

The code below works, but the problem I'm having is it has a tendency to display the same banner twice. Obviously, with only 6 different banners, there's a decent chance of this happening. However, on several occasions it ended up displaying the same banner 3 or 4 times in a row.

So, my question, is there a better way to display random banners? Is there a problem with my code posted below that is causing this to happen? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randInt(n) {
        randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*n);
        return randNum;
    }

    function adDescription(n) {
        var descrip = new Array();
        descrip[1]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";
        descrip[2]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";
        descrip[3]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";
         descrip[4]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";
        descrip[5]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";
        descrip[6]="Support Us -- Donate Money Today";

        return descrip[n];
    }

    function adLink(n) {
        var link = new Array();
        link[1]="url";
        link[2]="url";
        link[3]="url";
        link[4]="url";
        link[5]="url";
        link[6]="url";

        return link[n];
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="main">
<div id="ads">
  <script type="text/javascript">
var rNumber = randInt(6); //generate a random integer form 1 to 6
    var rAd = adDescription(rNumber); //description of the random ad
    var rLink = adLink(rNumber); //URL of the random ad

    document.write("<a href='" + rLink + "'>");
    document.write("<img src='ad" + rNumber + ".jpg' alt='" + rAd + "' />");
    document.write("</a>");

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off using a function like this:

```
function randInt(n) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1;
}
// randInt(7) returns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6
```

Reason being that in your version, if you called `randInt(6)` you could get return values of 0-6, which is actually 7 numbers rather than 6 numbers. Granted, the chance of returning 0 is incredibly small (would only happen if `Math.random()` returned exactly `0.000`), but could still throw things off. This is because `Math.ceil(0) = 0`

Comment: `Math.Random()` returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). It can never return 1.